# After Heroku deployment React client fails with Axios when specifying localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, http, axios

I have a React client and a NODE.JS server.

Client on port 3000 , Server on 5000.

When I make requests from the client it looks like this :

```
import axios from "axios";
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
baseURL: "http://localhost:5000"
});

try {
const res = await axiosInstance.post("/api/myRoute", ....);

... more code 
}


catch(...) { 

}
```

The problem is that when I upload the app to Heroku , the client gets 404 for the Axios requests , even though I used in `server.js` , `process.env.PORT` :

```
  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
  app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

How can we use Axios on Heroku so without specifying `localhost` as the `baseUrl` ?

Comment: How exactly is the app deployed to Heroku? Dynos can't bind two ports, so is the backend serving the frontend or do you have two dynos? If the former, I'd expect relative routes to work, no baseURL needed (just use a proxy in dev). If the latter, you'll need to tell the frontend where to find the backend (and, for CORS, vice versa). But if you're expecting the client app to make a call to *the client's localhost* and have that hit the backend *on Heroku*, that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You can set api url in [environment variables])(https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) so a production build will have the correct base url.

Comment: Since this is React code, it will run in the browser. In other words, `localhost` will point to the user's machine, not the heroku server.

Comment: @Chris G : And this what I'm trying to solve ...don't want to specify `localhost` !

Comment: 1. Ditch the `baseURL` setting. 2. build the react app 3. copy the built files into the node app's static files folder 4. deploy the node app to heroku

Comment: 5. Use a proxy for local dev. See this setup I put together, for example https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit

Comment: @jonrsharpe: What do you mean by "Use a proxy for local dev" ?  I have in `package.json` the line :  `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` but it doesn't help
`

Comment: I literally mean use a proxy, so the client can make relative requests and they still get sent to the server even though it's on a different port. If you've set the CRA proxy correctly you shouldn't need the baseURL for local dev. What do you mean *"didn't help"*? If you expected that to change things *on Heroku*, again that doesn't make sense.

Comment: You dont need the baseURL simply use relative URLs like `/api/route` it will work

Comment: @ImranKhan: When I do so we get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
`

Comment: Can you share your package.json file? You need to have `"heroku-postbuild": "yarn run build:prod"` in your package.json so that your node server is started after deployment

Comment: @ImranKhan you don't need a heroku-postbuild script for that, as long as start does something sensible.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes sorry I mistaken it with the start command `"start": "node server/server.js"` as this start command is needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In development when you go to `localhost:3000` you visit the development server that `create-react-app` scripts started for you with `npm start`. That server then sends down the development bundle of your app to your browser.

You will also will have started a second server for your api `localhost:5000`. This is the server that your React app (which now is running in the browser) makes local api requests to.

You (probably) won't have 2 servers running in production based on your setup. You'll instead have your node/express backend serve your build file when there is a request that isn't handled by your api routing *(and thus is likely a client side route)*

Assuming a project structure like so:

```
-> MyCoolApp
  -> index.js // express server
  -> client // create-react-app application
     -> src
        -> index.js
        -> setupProxy.js
```

**First** set up `http-proxy-middleware` in order to make api requests to your server from your client side app the same way in development and production using `axios.get('/api/route')`

```
// place in src with index.js no need to import anywhere
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware')

module.exports = function(app) {
    // add other server routes to path array
    app.use(proxy(['/api' ], { target: 'http://localhost:5000' }));
}
```

**Next** Set up your server index.js so that it behaves differently in production/staging vs development *(assuming you are using express)*:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

require('./routes')(app); //these are your api routes

//Non api requests in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'staging') {
    // Add production middleware such as redirecting to https

    // Express will serve up production assets i.e. main.js
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client/build'));
    // If Express doesn't recognize route serve index.html
    const path = require('path');
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html')
        );
    });
}

//start server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000; //Heroku sets port dynamically
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('listening...');
}).on('error', err => {
    console.log(`Error Code: ${err.code}`);
});
```

**Finally** when Heroku finishes installing the root dependancies it will then run a script called `heroku-postbuild` which you can instruct heroku to install your client dependancies and build your production React app

In your server package.json add/modify these scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "node index.js",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
```

This last part is helpful as Heroku is git based and it is bad practice to commit your build directory/files to git *(make sure to add the build directory to your `gitignore` if you keep builds locally!)*

Also Heroku by default only installs production dependencies (not any development dependencies) if this is the desired behavior you can leave out the `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false`

Comment: Thanks a lot, the middleware you added is what did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Willman I fixed the problem - for anyone who encounters the same problem , just add this :

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware')

module.exports = function(app) {
    // add other server routes to path array
    app.use(proxy(['/api' ], { target: 'http://localhost:5000' }));
}
```

To your `server.js / index.js` on the server side.

Thanks @Willman.

Comment: So there's no need to use the axios instance anymore? or do you still leave that